# Blow off tubes are cloudy

Tags: fermentation, equipment

I have 2 clear blow off tubes and both have become cloudy and a little yellow. 1. Can this be cleaned? 2. If not will it effect my beer as it's just a blow off tube. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd say just soak them in PBW and then sanitize with Star-San. Keeping those tubes stain-free is tough. As long as they're cleaned and sanitized, no worries.

Answer (score 3):

They will have no negative effects on your beer. Craftmeister alkaline wash might clean them, but it's really n o big deal.  All of mine look like that.